# Setting the accessibilityFrame of an element whose parent view will move

Tags: ios, accessibility

I have a UITableView with a custom header (i.e. I create the UIView myself). I need to tweak the accessibilityFrame of one of the subviews of the view, but I can’t figure out how to set the coordinates of the frame appropriately—they need to be relative to the window, but I’m not sure how to accomplish that.

My code looks like

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger) section
{
    CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, [tableView frame].size.width, 48);
    UIView *header = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];

    UILabel *labelOne = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:
        CGRectMake(0, 0, bounds.size.width - 80, 18)];
    UILabel *labelTwo = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:
        CGRectMake(0, 20, bounds.size.width - 80, 18)];

    CGRect frameOne = [labelOne frame];
    CGRect frameTwo = [labelTwo frame];

    [labelTwo setIsAccessibilityElement:NO];
    [labelOne setAccessibilityFrame:CGRectUnion(frameOne, frameTwo)];

    // ...

    return header;
}
```

I’ve got two UILabels, which I want to combine into one for the purposes of VoiceOver. I accomplish this by ignoring the second label and extending the frame of the first label to cover the area of the second label. (The second label is immediately below the first.) The problem is getting the frames. If I use the code as shown above, the accessibility frame is the correct size, but is positioned as if the UITableView’s header were in the top left corner of the screen. I tried to modify the code to say

```
CGRect frameOne = [header convertRect:[labelOne frame] toView:nil];
CGRect frameTwo = [header convertRect:[labelTwo frame] toView:nil];
```

but the same thing happened. Shouldn’t this latter piece of code convert the UILabels’ frames into window-relative coordinates?

I thought maybe the issue is that when the UIView is created, it doesn’t know where on screen it’s going to be positioned (and as part of a UITableView it may be scrolled all over the place). Is it necessary to implement accessibilityFrame as a message which checks the UIView’s position each time it is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a helper function that will assist you with doing exactly that: [UIAccessibilityConvertFrameToScreenCoordinates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uikitfunctionreference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIAccessibilityConvertFrameToScreenCoordinates). This function takes a `CGRect` and converts it from a view's coordinate system into screen coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's the timing of when the `UIView` is created, as I believe the `window` should be not-`nil` by the time `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` is called.  I think the problem is the receiver of the `convertRect:toView:` message.  Rather than passing this message to `header`, you should be passing it to `[self view]`.

You're converting from the *receivers* coordinate system to that of another view, in this case `nil` or the `UIWindow` in your app.  When `header` receives this message, you're converting from *`header`'s* coordinate system to `window`'s coordinate system, but `header` itself is a subview of `[self view]`.  Instead, you want to ask `[self view]` to do the conversion, which should take into account any `UINavigationBar`'s, etc.

```
CGRect frameOne = [[self view] convertRect:[labelOne frame] toView:nil];
CGRect frameTwo = [[self view] convertRect:[labelTwo frame] toView:nil];
```